# [C++][Makefile] No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm learning Makefile and I have a problem.

This is my project structure:

```
root
├── include/
│   └── all .h files here
├── src/
│   └── all .c files here
├── bin/
│   └── output binary
└── Makefile
└── Main.cpp
```

And this is my makefile:

```
IMPL_DIR := src
HEADER_DIR := include
BIN_DIR := bin

output: main.o filemanager.o
    g++ -std=c++0x -Wall main.o filemanager.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/login

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

filemanager.o: $(HEADER_DIR)/CFileManager.hpp $(IMPL_DIR)/CFileManager.cpp
    g++ -c CFileManager.cpp 

$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

And I have such error:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: CFileManager.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "CFileManager.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:9: main.o] Error 1
```

Anyone can help me with this error? Is it problem with my code or project structure?
I'm not sure but I think that I should use -I parameter, but I don't know how.

---

UPDATE:

This Makefile works:

```
IMPL_DIR := src
HEADER_DIR := include
BIN_DIR := bin

output: main.o CFileManager.o
    g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -I$(HEADER_DIR) main.o CFileManager.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/login

main.o: main.cpp | $(BIN_DIR)
    g++ -I$(HEADER_DIR) -c main.cpp

CFileManager.o: $(HEADER_DIR)/CFileManager.hpp $(IMPL_DIR)/CFileManager.cpp
    g++ -I$(HEADER_DIR) -c $(IMPL_DIR)/CFileManager.cpp 

$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

But if I want add line at the end:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

This command doesn't clean*.o objects. Why?

Comment: Did you run `make clean`?

Comment: Okay, so I cannot do this automatically? I mean, when I run make, and at the end makefile deploy clean at the end?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know why you'd want to do that.  It seems to entirely defeat the purpose of using a makefile since your entire project will be rebuilt from scratch every time you run `make`.  You might as well just use a shell script that contains the compile and link lines and do away with the makefile completely.  In any event, the simplest way to do it is just add the `rm` command into the recipe that builds your binary, so after `g++ ... -o $(BINDIR)/login` add another line saying `rm -f *.o`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any usage of `-I$(HEADER_DIR)` in compiler flags.

```
IMPL_DIR := src
HEADER_DIR := include
BIN_DIR := bin

output: main.o filemanager.o
    g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -I$(HEADER_DIR) main.o filemanager.o -o $(BIN_DIR)/login

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -I$(HEADER_DIR) -c main.cpp

filemanager.o: $(HEADER_DIR)/CFileManager.hpp $(IMPL_DIR)/CFileManager.cpp
    g++ -I$(HEADER_DIR) -c CFileManager.cpp 

$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

If you want automatic clean, add the rule before any other rule

```
all: output clean
```

Comment: I replied in answer to the topic